# narrowing conversion from int to long unsigned int {} is ill-formed in C++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc-warning, gcc4.8

when I run the below code - I'm getting the warning "narrowing conversion from int to long unsigned int inside {} is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]. I'm using GNU 4.8 compiler.

```
typedef struct TableEntry
{
    unsigned long value;
    const char *label;
} TableEntry;

enum FunctionType
{
    NORMAL   = 0, 
    RANGE    = 1
};


TableEntry functionTypes[] = 
{
    {NORMAL,   "NORMAL"},
    {RANGE, "RANGE"}
};
```

I don't understand why compiler is considering enum as an int?
Is this a bug in GCC 4.8?  Is there any workaround? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe enums are always considered `int`s behind-the-scenes. If you don't specify the values of your enum values, they default to 0, 1, 2, ... In this case you should be okay with the implicit conversion, though, since the conversion shouldn't cost you any accuracy.

Comment: We have these warnings in every file. about 150 files . My boss doesn't like to see the warnings.

Comment: This is valid C++03 code so g++'s warning is most likely unfounded. It would be noteworthy indeed if the C++11 standard broke C++03 code wholesale. That said, this is just another reason for not using unsigned integers for *number* values.

Comment: As long as you're certain the implicit conversion won't cause you any problems, you _could_ temporarily disable the warning. But I really don't suggest that for a long-term solution, since having that warning enabled might save you headaches in other data-conversion scenarios.

Comment: enum FunctionType : unsigned long { /* etc */ };  This is doing it backwards, do fix the struct declaration instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If practical do:

```
enum FunctionType
{
    NORMAL   = 0, 
    RANGE    = 1
};

typedef struct TableEntry
{
    FunctionType value;
    const char *label;
} TableEntry;


TableEntry functionTypes[] = 
{
    {NORMAL,   "NORMAL"},
    {RANGE, "RANGE"}
};
```

Otherwise, change the type in the struct to `int`, or explicitly base the enumeration on the same type as in the struct.

<del>Btw., I the think g++ warning is unfounded and wrong, since the original code is valid C++03.</del> *Correction:* As I understand it now, the diagnostic is correct, and this is a breaking change in C++11. I just couldn't believe it.

---

About the naming convention: those all uppercase identifiers are good for Java programmers (who are used to that convention), but in C++ they increase the chances of inadvertent text substitution. There are also the aesthetic considerations. Much win in reserving all uppercase for macros.

Comment: Can you point to the source for the information that this is a breaking change in c++11?

Comment: @Dave: The code in the question is one example. It's fine as C++03, invalid as C++11. That's what “breaking” means, that it breaks existing code.

Answer (score 4):

Usually underlying type of unscoped enumerations is int ( it can be any integral type that can represent all values of enumerators).

However I do not see any narrowing conversion because type unsigned long can represent all values of type int.

EDIT: It seems I am wrong because I found an example in the Standard that contradicts my assumption

```
unsigned int ui1 = {-1}; // error: narrows
```

So unsigned int can not be initialized by using an initializer list that contains a negative number.

So to avoid the warning the enumeration could be written as

```
enum FunctionType : unsigned int // or unsigned long
{
    NORMAL   = 0, 
    RANGE    = 1
};
```

Comment: int can take negative values, where as unsigned long cannot.  hence narrowing conversion

Comment: About half of the `int` values can not be represented as `unsigned long`.

Comment: @srinivas All values of type int including negative can be represented by type unsigned long. Type unsigned long is the common type for int and unsigned long.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf As I understand the Standard all values of int including negative can be represented by type unsigned long.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  It seems you are right. I uodated my post.

Comment: @srinivas It seems you are right. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

- you could change "value" to int
- or you could use the new "enum class" (c++11) which is strongly typed, and declare your "value" as this type.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. I got these warnings in about 150 files.Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Interesting, my first two recommendations would have been: change the type of `value` to a `FunctionType`, or make `FunctionType` backed by `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using c++11, you could declare your enum like so:
`enum Enum2 : unsigned char;`
That should force the enum to work. That said, IDEONE has no warnings/errors for your posted code. Could just be GCC being overly pedantic.